# Is it possible to run a script whenever you enter a directory on Windows?

Tags: windows, command-line, automation

I have a Python virtual environment created in a subfolder of a project. Whenever I need to work with this project, I have to manually activate this virtual environment.

```
c:\my_projects\project1>venv\Scripts\activate.bat
(venv) c:\my_projects\project1>
```

Is there a ways to automatically execute a specified script (`venv\Scripts\activate.bat` in this case) whenever I enter a specific folder in Windows command line?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42735/run-a-script-automatically-as-i-switch-to-a-directory but I know it's Windows. Maybe someone knows of an equilevant or some sort of hack or PowerShell terminal solution. Not sure if you could alias `cd` to run a script that does the cd to the directory specified but also runs some conditional logic like if `%cd%` equals a specific directory to then execute the batch.

Comment: Why not just add the path to your bat to your $PATH so you just have type `activate`?

Comment: @Keltari It's because that directory is only relevant to this project. If I have multiple projects and each has its own `activate.bat`, I can't add them all in PATH.

Comment: Yes. Which version of Windows? You can create a service and run code automatically on an event. Easier if you use WSL and do it in Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want this to only work for `CD` commands you type inside CMD.EXE then you could alias `cd` to your own batch script which make the cd change and sets up vars as appropriate. Create your own script `C:\yourpath\cd.cmd`:

```
@echo off
echo CD from %CD% to %1

cd %1
if "%CD%" == "C:\yourspecialdir" (
    echo RUN BATCH SCRIPT for %CD%
) else (
    echo TODO: undo above settings or reset PWD NOW: %CD%
)
```

In CMD.EXE register cd to your new script:

```
doskey cd=C:\yourpath\cd.cmd $*
```

Like Windows scripting in general, this isn't very robust so won't work inside your own scripts or if you have `setlocal` in any setup script you may source from inside `cd.cmd`.

Comment: Very interesting idea! I'll give it a try. Thank you for the answer!

Comment: `if /i` to do a case-insensitive comparison would be better

Comment: @phuclv - yes `if /i`is generally a better choice unless Windows or NAS case-sensitive filesystem is enabled.